# Coderay renders actual ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-highlighting, redcloth, coderay

I have RedCloth with Coderay installed to highlight my code pasted in my blog.

If I paste some code like this:

```
 CodeRay.scan(
"set_meta_tags :og => {
        :title => @blog.title,
        :type => 'article',
        :url => current_url,
        :image => @blog.blog_images.first.image.url,
        :article => {:published_time => @blog.created_at.to_time.iso8601,
                     :modified_time => @blog.updated_at.to_time.iso8601,
                     :author => 'Name',
                     :section => @blog.categories.first.name,
                     :tags => @blog.categories.map(&:name).join(', ')
        }}",
:ruby).div(:css => :class)
```

I got this

```
set_meta_tags :og => {

        :title => blog</span>.title,
        <span class="symbol">:type</span> =&gt; <span class="string"><span class="delimiter">'</span><span class="content">article</span><span class="delimiter">'</span></span>,
        <span class="symbol">:url</span> =&gt; current_url,
        <span class="symbol">:image</span> =&gt; <span class="instance-variable">blog.blog_images.first.image.url,

        :article => {:published_time => blog</span>.created_at.to_time.iso8601,
                     <span class="symbol">:modified_time</span> =&gt; <span class="instance-variable">blog.updated_at.to_time.iso8601,

                     :author => ‘Name’,

                     :section => blog</span>.categories.first.name,
                     <span class="symbol">:tags</span> =&gt; <span class="instance-variable">blog.categories.map(&:name).join(‘, ’)

        }}
```

How can I get rid of that?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi, Its rendering the <span class="symbol">blah</span> instead of coloring the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the markup through [`sanitize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) before outputting it in the view. This will keep harmless html tags, but strip potentially harmful things such as `<script>`:

```
<%= sanitize CodeRay.scan(..., :ruby).div(:css => :class) %>
```

If you can trust the markup 100% (I think you can in this case), you can use [`raw`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html) to bypass escaping or `html_safe` to mark the string as safe. This will lead to *all* tags being outputted.

```
<%= raw CodeRay.scan(..., :ruby).div(:css => :class) %>
```

or

```
<%= CodeRay.scan(..., :ruby).div(:css => :class).html_safe %>
```

Also see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety

Comment: Thank you, I accept this answer. But I am using also ```textilize``` before the ```CodeRay``` part. When I prepend like this: ```textilize(sanitize CodeRay("blahCode", :ruby).div``` I got the same result back

Comment: Why would you want textile to process your code listing? You could do: `sanitize textilize(CodeRay("blahCode", :ruby).div.html_safe)` to pass the raw output to textilize

Comment: Hm. doesnt worked. I simply wanna format my "regular text" and put some code between.

Comment: That will not work. What if your code contains `a * b * c`? It will render as a **b** c, because it thinks you want to make the `b` bold. You have to scan the input for code blocks and then pass that through coderay separately. You should read this: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/207-syntax-highlighting

Comment: I watched this already, thank you. I switched now back to html :-) But I ran into another issue. It does not render greater_than signs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057970/coderay-does-not-render-greater-than-signs